# How to execute xdg-open from NERDTree in Linux?

Tags: external-command, linux, plugin-nerdtree, key-bindings

`Netrw` able to execute file with `xdg-open` by pressing <kbd>x</kbd>, how about `NERDTree` ?

**[Response to downvote]**

If `xdg-open` can so easy/direct to work (which is the reason of downvote), then what's the point for this plugin (https://github.com/aufgang001/vim-nerdtree_plugin_open) exist ? Of course i do a quick try but it didn't work too.

Comment: Try `:help nerdtree`.

Comment: Thanks for those downvote because i'm not even can make help manual work for NERDTree. Both `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` and `help ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/doc/` doesn't work. Which keyword should i use to grep the 1253 lines' help file ? `external` and `xdg` doesn't work. and simply `o` is open file in vim, not `xdg-open`.

Comment: You are not supposed to "grep" the help file; you are supposed to "read" it. Once you have read it and it doesn't mention xdg-open anywhere, what conclusion can you make about NERDTree's ability to use xdg-open? Anyway, this place is not a support board for random plugins. Use their issue tracker.

Answer (score 6):

For those curious, if NerdTree can xdg-open: Yes it can.

- Put the cursor on the desired file.
- Press *m* for the context menu.
- Press *o* to open in the system editor.
- Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

I figure out the reason why [this plugin](https://github.com/aufgang001/vim-nerdtree_plugin_open) doesn't work:

> git clone https://github.com/aufgang001/vim-nerdtree_plugin_open.git ~/.vim/vim-nerdtree_plugin_open.git

The instruction is wrong, it should put inside `~/.vim/bundle` (at least in my case):

```
git clone https://github.com/aufgang001/vim-nerdtree_plugin_open.git  ~/.vim/bundle/vim-nerdtree_plugin_open.git
```